# Написать функцию на JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Дан массив [1,1,1,4,4,5,1,6,6,74,74,74,3]. Написать функцию, которая вернет массив только из тех чисел, которые
повторялись в исходном. Массив, который возвращает
функция [1,4,6,74].

Помогите реализовать на чистом JS.

Comment: А самому попробовать решить?

Comment: @Dantessss не могу догадаться как сделать. у меня выводит 1,1,4,6,74,3

Comment: выложи свой код, посмотрим в чем ошибка, но вообще я выложил свое решение

Comment: @Dantessss пытаюсь разобраться по твоему коду. в принципе смысл понятен, но я делал через циклы for, который 1 пробегает по первому элементу и сравнивает с последующим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function a(_i) {
  let _o = {};
  _i.forEach(function(i, j) {
    if (!_o[i])
      _o[i] = 0;
    _o[i] += 1;
  });
  _i = [];
  for (let i in _o) {
    if (_o[i] > 1)
      _i.push(i);
  }
  return _i;
}

console.log(a([1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 1, 6, 6, 74, 74, 74, 3]));
```